# Discord.js Deleting channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot using discord.js, I need to do a control every time a specified channel is deleted, do you know how to do it? I searched on the guide but I didn't find anything

Comment: What do you mean by _"need to do a control"_?

Comment: There is a [`channelDelete` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelDelete)

Comment: I mean that I need to do a check when a specified channel is deleted, for example, if I have 3 channels called "channel 1", "channel 2", "channel 3", I need to do the control, for example, only on the channel that is called "channel 2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you checked the [Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelDelete) ?
Try checking it again.
Here's an example:

```js
Client.on("channelDelete", channel=> {
    console.log(`${channel.name} Was deleted`);
})
```

For a specific channel

```js
Client.on("channelDelete", channel=> {
    if(channel.id === "TheSpeceficChannelID"){
        console.log(`The channel ${channel.name} Was deleted`);
    }
})
```

Comment: I found this example but this doesn't help me because this is a function that is launched every time any channel is deleted, I need to do launch a function every time a specified channel is deleted, this works with generic channels, I have to check if the id of the deleted channel is a specified id